# Multiple coloums in an array list

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to fetch all the columns from my sqllite database to an ArrayList.My table name is Products.I have created an ArrayList adapter name Product.I am fetching my tables value in DBHELPER class.But when I am using ArrayList add to add all the columns value in my arrayadapter I got the following error

> Cannot resolve method add(java.lang.string, java.lang.string)

**DBHELPER.JAVA**

```
public ArrayList<Product> getProductdetails()
{
    ArrayList<Product> array_list = new ArrayList<Product>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                String product_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PRODUCT_NAME"));
                String Quantity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Quantity"));
                String PROD_VAT = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PROD_VAT"));

                array_list.add(product_name,Quantity,PROD_VAT,PROD_VAT);
               // array_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(product_name,Quantity,PROD_VAT,PROD_VAT));
            }
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

**PRODUCT.JAVA**

```
 public class Product {
//private variables

String _PRODUCT_CODE;
String _PRODUCT_NAME;
String _PRODUCT_RATE;
String _PRODUCT_VAT;
// Empty constructor
public Product(){

}
// constructor
public Product(String PRODUCT_CODE, String PRODUCT_NAME, String PRODUCT_RATE,String PRODUCT_VAT){
    this._PRODUCT_CODE = PRODUCT_CODE;
    this._PRODUCT_NAME = PRODUCT_NAME;
    this._PRODUCT_RATE = PRODUCT_RATE;
    this._PRODUCT_VAT = PRODUCT_VAT;
}


public String getproductcode(){ return this._PRODUCT_CODE;}

public String getproductname(){
    return this._PRODUCT_NAME;
}
public String getproductrate(){return this._PRODUCT_RATE;}
public String getproductvat(){return this._PRODUCT_VAT;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding data to `ArrayList` in wrong way. Your `ArrayList` is type of object (eg. your `Product` class), So you need to pass instance of model class.

```
array_list.add(new Product(code,name,rate,vat));
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats solved the issue. I had flaws in the concept.

Comment: @AbdurRahman your flaw is using `ArrayAdapter` - use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead

Comment: yup `SimpleCursorAdapter` would be great but @pskink what if he is using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`

Comment: then he should use [CursorRecyclerAdapter](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Arraylist` is type of Product which is one model class , so you have to add model class in that `arraylist` like this :

```
array_list.add(new Product(product_name,Quantity,PROD_VAT,PROD_VAT));
```

Answer (score 1):

`addAll()` method of `java.util.ArrayList class`. This method is used for adding all the elements of a list to the another list.

What you want to is fetching single record & adding it to array list, and what you where trying to code is adding a single item as collection in to array list, which is wrong.

You need to add every single model as following way,

```
array_list.add(new Product(product_name,Quantity,PROD_VAT,PROD_VAT));
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify

```
array_list.add(product_name,Quantity,PROD_VAT,PROD_VAT);
```

To

```
array_list.add(new Product(product_name,Quantity,PROD_VAT,PROD_VAT));
```

Comment: Sorry, we must have been typing the answer at the same time. Is that a reason for down voting?